# How to create single Apex method for all object triggers? (Generic method)

Tags: apex, trigger, dynamic-apex

I need to Update parent and Other child records when the child record is updated or inserted. This same logic is for all object triggers.

Tried to implement below logic:

```
global abstract class abstracttriggercontext{
global static void run(String objectName, System.TriggerOperation operationType, List<sobject> newList, List<sobject> oldList,
                       Map<Id, sobject> newMap, Map<Id, sobject> oldMap){
                           //query the meta data
                           for (TriggerContext__mdt record : getMetaData(objectName,operationType)){
                               //get the instance
                               AbstractTriggerContext instance = (AbstractTriggerContext)Type.forName(record.Class_Name__c).newInstance();
                               //call the method
                               if (operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT){
                                   
                                   instance.beforeInsert(newList, oldList, newMap, oldMap);
                               }else if (operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_UPDATE) {
                                   instance.beforeUpdate (newList, oldList, newMap, oldMap);
                               }else if (operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_DELETE){
                                   instance.beforeDelete(oldList, oldMap);
                               }else if (operationType == System.TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT) {
                                   instance.afterInsert(newlist, oldList, newMap, oldMap);
                               }else if (operationType == system.TriggerOperation.AFTER_UPDATE){
                                   instance.afterUpdate(newList, oldList, newMap, oldMap);
                               }else if (operationType == System.Triggeroperation.AFTER_UNDELETE){
                                   instance.afterUndelete(newList, newMap);
                               }
                           }
                       }
global virtual void beforeInsert(List<sobject> newList, List<sobject> oldList, Map<Id,sobject> newMap, Map<Id, sobject> oldmap){
    //override for before insert logic
}
global virtual void beforeUpdate (List<sobject> newlist, List<sobject> oldList, Map<Id,sobject> newMap, Map<Id, sobject> oldMap){
    //override for before update logic
}
global virtual void afterInsert (List<sobject> newList, List<sObject> oldList, Map<Id, sobject> newMap, Map<Id, sObject> oldMap){
    //override for after insert logic
}
global virtual void afterUpdate(List<sobject> newList, List<sobject> oldList, Map<Id,sobject> newMap, Map<Id, sobject> oldMap){
    //override for after update logic
}
global virtual void beforeDelete(List<sobject> oldList, Map<Id, sobject> oldMap){
    //override for before delete logic
}
global virtual void afterundelete(List<sobject> newList, Map<Id, sobject> newMap){
   
    //override for after undelete logic
}
global static List<TriggerContext__mdt> getMetaData(String objectName, System.TriggerOperation operationType){
    String query = 'Select Class_Name__c from TriggerContext__mdt where Class_Name__c !=null And Is_Active__c= true'+'AND Object_Name__c=:objectName';
    String context = '';
    if(operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT){
        context='AND Context__c = \'Before\' AND Operation__c = \'Insert\'';
    }else if(operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_UPDATE){
        context='AND Context__c = \'Before\' AND Operation__c = \'update\'';
    }else if(operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_DELETE){
        context='AND Context__c = \'Before\' AND Operation__c = \'delete\'';
    }else if(operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_INSERT){
        context='AND Context__c = \'After\' AND Operation__c = \'Insert\'';
    }else if(operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_UPDATE){
        context='AND Context__c = \'After\' AND Operation__c = \'Update\'';
    }else if(operationType == System.TriggerOperation.BEFORE_DELETE){
        context='AND Context__c = \'After\' AND Operation__c = \'Delete\'';
    }
   
    query +=context;
   
    return (List<TriggerContext__mdt>)Database.query(query);
}
```

}

```
global class IsPrimaryUpdate extends AbstractTriggerContext{
public string objecttype;
Map<ID, SObject> parentOpps = new Map<ID, SObject>();
Set<Id> CurrentObjectid = new Set<Id>();
global override void afterInsert(List<sobject>newList,List<sObject>oldList,Map<Id,sObject>newMap,Map<Id,sObject>oldMap){
    //override for before insert logic
    for(SObject sObj : newList){
        objecttype=string.valueof(sObj);
       if(sObj.Primary__c == true){
       CurrentObjectid.add(sObj.id);
    }
}
```

But I am not able to get objects and records exactly?

Can someone please guide me on how to implement the same logic for all objects?
we have the same field API Names in all objects.

I am getting error at `if(sObj.Primary__c == true){`
Vairable does not exist: Primary__c

The below example code is for a single object. I am trying to implement same logic for all objects from only one method.

```
Set<Id> Opportunityid = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> OpportunityMOid = new Set<Id>();

 if(trigger.isafter && (trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate) ){
for(Opportunity_Market_Offering__c d : trigger.new){
    if(d.Primary__c == true){
        Opportunityid.add(d.Opportunities__c);
        OpportunityMOid.add(d.id);
    }
  }
}


 OMO = [SELECT id,Primary__c FROM Opportunity_Market_Offering__c 
   WHERE Opportunities__c  IN:Opportunityid AND Primary__c =true AND Id 
 NOT IN:OpportunityMOid];
```

Comment: Please clarify where specifically you are stuck (via **[edit]**). Also not your query has a typo with a single underscore in `TriggerContext_mdt `.

Comment: Hi, @AdrianLarson Thanks for your response. I have updated my question. Please guide me accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In Apex there are describe calls available for SObjects and SObject fields that allow you to discover the relationships, and APIs that work across all types. Together, these allow you yo write one piece of code that deals with many types of SObject.

On describe calls, for example, see `getReferenceTo()` in the [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm).

The APIs that work across all types are detailed in the [SObject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm). This allow you to create SObjects and set fields without having dependencies on specific types.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use dynamic `SObject.get`. Generic `SObject` does not support static field retrieval (except for `Id`).

**Incorrect**

```
if(sObj.Primary__c == true)
```

**Correct**

```
if (sObj.get('Primary__c') == true)
```

Comment: Ok, @AdrianLarson I got it but how do we query (OMO)?  I mentioned in my question. Querying child records from parent?

Comment: You in fact did _not_ make clear any problems you have hit while attempting to execute your query.